# Setting up my very own VPN connection

Tags: vpn

as you can see from the title I'm asking a noob question about VPN. I tried to follow some step-by-step guides off of Youtube but they end up not working. What I like to do is setting up a VPN Tunnel at my grandparents who live in another country so I can visit the web through their connection. All they have is a PC an a router.
Could anyone be so kind and help me with this one?
Thanks.

-edit: Win7 installed

Comment: Add some details. Which OS is installed on your grandpa's computer? What is your router? Cisco? Mikrotik? etc?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that you are using Windows 7 or later.

Go to **Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections** . Press `Alt` key to extended menu be appeared. Select **File** menu and **New Incoming Connection**. Select which user can connect to this VPN server (You should username and password using to login to your grandparents computer for connecting to the VPN server). Follow remain steps. Now your grandparents computer act as a VPN server). Create VPN client and connect to it.

Comment: This works if the VPN server has a public IP address and isnt behind NAT.

Comment: What about the router forwarding the requests to the computer with the set up commection? Is a port forwarding enough? Which port would that be?

Comment: For many Modem Routers port forwarding is enough. Forward TCP port 1723.